# How to make Agda pretty-print products nicely

Tags: agda

Consider the following self-contained program:

```
 module Test where

  record Σ {A : Set} (B : A -> Set) : Set where
    constructor _,_
    field
      fst : A
      snd : B fst
  open Σ public

  infixr 0 _,_

  _×_ : Set -> Set -> Set
  A × B = Σ (\ (_ : A) -> B)

  infixr 10 _×_

  f : {A B : Set} → A × B → A
  f x = {!!}
```

If you C-c C-l in the goal, you get:

```
Goal: .A
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
x  : Σ (λ _ → .B)
.B : Set
.A : Set
```

i.e. you see the underlying sigma, and the type of the binder of the lambda is hidden. This is pretty annoying. Is there a way to make Agda show the type of binders that don't bind names by default?

This is Agda 2.3.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agda 2.4.3 displays `x  : .A × .B`.

You can use the [abstract](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.VisibilityAndEvaluation) keyword:

```
abstract
  _×_ : Set -> Set -> Set
  A × B = Σ (\ (_ : A) -> B)

  fst' : ∀ {A B} -> A × B -> A
  fst' (x , y) = x

  snd' : ∀ {A B} -> A × B -> B
  snd' (x , y) = y
```

But that's definitely overkill (and it looks like pattern synonyms do not work in abstract blocks).

It's much more annoying to me, that Agda doesn't want to reduce functions like `flip` and especially `_∘_`, but unfolds some functions with really long definitions. Agda needs a mechanism for fixing these problems.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this problem has been fixed in the latest version of Agda, so you should upgrade.